# How does __USE_MISC referenced in glibc work?

Tags: linux, gcc, glibc

I'm just wondering how `__USE_MISC` works and where it's documented. I see a bunch of functions inside `.h` files require it and mention it. But it seems something is actively undefining it and I would like to know is doing that and how it makes that decision?

```
#define __USE_MISC 1
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  printf("%d\n", __USE_MISC);
}
```

Returns

> error: use of undeclared identifier '`__USE_MISC`'

That error goes away if I call it anything else, like `_USE_MISC`, or `USE_MISC` or `foobar`.

I've tried this with clang and gcc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `__USE_*` macros are not supposed to be defined and checked by the user, they're a mechanism to implement the feature selectors (`_XOPEN_SOURCE`, `_GNU_SOURCE`, etc) in glibc headers.

The whole mechanism is documented in a comment in the [`features.h`](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=include/features.h;h=ba272078cf2263ec88e039fda7524c136a4a7953;hb=HEAD) header.

The `features.h` header is included from most standard headers (eg. from `stdio.h`) and the first thing it does is to undefine all the `__USE_*` macros, and then define them selectively depending on the `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`, `_GNU_SOURCE`, etc. macros defined by the user. Then the standard headers will ifdef things in and out based on those `__USE_*` macros.

One may wonder how to map back from a `__USE_*` macro to a `_*_SOURCE` macro that turns it on; for instance, one may want to compile their program with `gcc -ansi`, see that the `psignal()` function is only defined when the `__USE_XOPEN2K8` is on, and wants to know what `_*_SOURCE` selector will get them that. Here is a table, generated with a script that had run `gcc -ansi -E -dM "-D$source" -include features.h` with different selectors:

```
__USE_ATFILE
        _ATFILE_SOURCE  _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE
        _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=200809L  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=700
__USE_FILE_OFFSET64
        _FILE_OFFSET_BITS>=64
__USE_GNU
        _GNU_SOURCE
__USE_ISOC11
        _GNU_SOURCE  _ISOC11_SOURCE
__USE_ISOC95
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _ISOC11_SOURCE  _ISOC99_SOURCE
        _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=200112L  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=600
__USE_ISOC99
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _ISOC11_SOURCE  _ISOC99_SOURCE
        _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=200112L  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=600
__USE_LARGEFILE
        _GNU_SOURCE  _LARGEFILE_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_LARGEFILE64
        _GNU_SOURCE  _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
__USE_MISC
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE
__USE_POSIX
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  _POSIX_SOURCE
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_POSIX199309
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=199309L
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_POSIX199506
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=199506L
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_POSIX2
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=2
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_POSIX_IMPLICITLY
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_REENTRANT
        _REENTRANT  _THREAD_SAFE
__USE_UNIX98
        _GNU_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_XOPEN
        _GNU_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
__USE_XOPEN2K
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=200112L
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=600
__USE_XOPEN2K8
        _DEFAULT_SOURCE  _GNU_SOURCE  _POSIX_C_SOURCE>=200809L
        _XOPEN_SOURCE>=700
__USE_XOPEN2K8XSI
        _GNU_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=700
__USE_XOPEN2KXSI
        _GNU_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=600
__USE_XOPEN_EXTENDED
        _GNU_SOURCE  _XOPEN_SOURCE>=500
```